# How can I update the textbox value to the bindingsource using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, bindingsource

Consider this code:

```
txtLastModifyUserID.DataBindings.Add("Text", c_bsDataSetSource, "LastModifyUserID");
txtLastModifyUserID.Text = "1234";
```

Why cannot the source be updated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DataBinding doesn't usually *write* the value until after the control starts to lose focus.  Since you are updating the TextBox programmatically, the DataBinding doesn't know there is something to update.

The way you wrote your code, you would have to call the `WriteValue()` method yourself (assuming only 1 databinding exists on the TextBox):

```
txtLastModifyUserID.DataBindings.Add("Text", c_bsDataSetSource, "LastModifyUserID");
txtLastModifyUserID.Text = "1234";
txtLastModifyUserID.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to specify `OnPropertyChanged` on `DataSourceUpdateMode`.

Comment: thanks, but it does't work,
the source cannot be updated i also try to change the DataSourceUpdateMode to onvalidation and then call DoValidate(), it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. Simply change your binding to "Value" instead of "Text". When you programmatically change this, as long as the datasource is updated, the human eye should catch the update. Also do specify `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`.